# Is DDD a throwback to BDUF?

Tags: c#, java, tdd, domain-driven-design

I'm new to DDD ([Domain-Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)), and I like many of it's ideas. But with DDD I need to spend pretty much time analyzing domain, defining entities and value objects, choosing aggregates and defining their boundaries etc. So I wonder - isn't it throwback to the BDUF ([Big Design Up Front](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Design_Up_Front))? Is there some good experience of putting DDD and Agile together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um... no.

DDD says *what* to do your in design - put your domain model at its core and derive the rest from there (that doesn't mean it needs to be complete).

Agile says *when* to do design - evolve it constantly rather than trying to get it perfectly right before you start coding.

That is no contradiction at all. For example, using DDD with Scrum, you'd choose the most important functionality that can be implemented in 30 days, identify the domain model required for that functionality and implement it based on that model within 30 days. Then you'd choose which functionality now has the highest priority and can be completed in 30 days, extend the domain model to support that functionality, and implement it.

Comment: But many examples I saw were done in up front design style. E.g. Eric Evans example with Cargos - he started with rough design of whole system.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: A "rough design of the whole system" is *anything but* BDUF. In its introduction, the book says "The example will step through a succession of model and design refinements as a hypothetical team deals with requirements and implementation issues - sounds like a textbook example of agile development to me.